# Why should I use sendrecv?

Tags: python, mpi

I am trying to teach myself the MPI message passing interface with mpi4py. I noticed that MPI had a function called "sendrecv". However, it is not listed in mpi4py documentation:
http://documen.tician.de/boostmpi/reference.html

Could I simply emulate the sendrecv function with say

```
  communicator.send(0xdeadbeef, dest=1, tag=0)
  data = communicator.recv(source=1, tag=0)
```

What does "sendrecv" do other than emulate a recv followed by a send? Where can I find mpi4py documentation that talks about it?

Comment: `MPI_SENDRECV` rather emulates a non-blocking send (`MPI_ISEND`), followed by a receive and a wait (`MPI_WAIT`) for the non-blocking operation to complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MPI_Sendrecv`](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node45.html#SECTION00360000000000000000) is a convenience function. It sends one message and receives one message, and guarantees that there will be no deadlocks due to each process waiting for another one to send.

Comment: Guarantee is a strong word, of course; it's certainly possible to write reasonable-looking communciation patterns with sendrecv() that deadlock.  The advantage of sendrecv is that it's a blocking (send + recv) rather than a blocking send followed by a blocking recv; it allows you to write *some* communications patterns that can't be safely done with send and recv without having to go all the way to isend + irecv + waitall.